# How to analyze PDF using ChatGPT / Vision python API?

Tags: python, pdf, openai-api, chatgpt-api

I have a list of pdf files and I want to analyze the first page of each document to extract information. I've tried a lot of free and paid OCR, but in my case, the results aren't good enough.

So I want to try using the ChatGPT API in python. How do I go about it?

Also, I saw in [openAI Vision documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/vision) that there is a `detail` parameter but there is no example provided, how do I use this parameter?

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you need to extact the first page of each document as **image** (here PNG).

```
import fitz

def save_first_page_as_png(pdf_path: str, image_path: str):
    pdf_document = fitz.open(pdf_path)
    first_page = pdf_document.load_page(0)
    pixmap = first_page.get_pixmap()
    pixmap.save(image_path)
```

Then, to call ChatGPT API you need to convert this image in **base64**.

```
import base64

def encode_image(image_path: str):
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        return base64.b64encode(image_file.read()).decode('utf-8')
```

Finally, you can call ChatGPT API (with the `detail` parameter).

```
import requests

api_key = 'your_api_key'

def call_gpt4_with_image(base64_image):
    headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": f"Bearer {api_key}"
    }

    payload = {
        "model": "gpt-4-vision-preview",
        "messages": [
            {
                "role": "user",
                "content": [
                    {
                        "type": "text",
                        "text": "Describe this image."
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "image_url",
                        "image_url": {
                            "url": f"data:image/png;base64,{base64_image}",
                            "detail": "low"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "max_tokens": 300
    }

    response = requests.post("https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions", headers=headers, json=payload)
    print(response.json())
```

Note that the parameter `detail` can be `low` or `high` (see the [documentation](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/vision?lang=python)).

Here is an example of a full workflow.

```
pdf_paths = ['pdf1.pdf', 'pdf2.pdf', 'pdf3.pdf']
for pdf_path in pdf_paths:
    first_page_path = pdf_path.replace('.pdf', '_1st_page.png')
    save_first_page_as_png(pdf_path, first_page_path)
    base64_image = encode_image(first_page_path)
    call_gpt4_with_image(base64_image)
```

**EDIT:**
In terms of [price](https://openai.com/pricing), I tried it on the first page of a pdf, the png was 596x842 pixels, the request (question + image) cost me 98 Input tokens and 87 Output tokens. With the current pricing of $0.01 / 1K Input tokens and $0.03 / 1K Output tokens, that's a total of $0.00359 ($3.59/1K images).

Comment: Why did you ask the question when you knew the answer straight away? Just karma hunting? 

Comment: Helping people with a use case I have, and adding an example of the `detail` parameter that is not on openAI documentation. [To be crystal clear, it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @SamuelHulla Is it not allowed on this site such stuffs? I did similar and was downvoted, it sucks.

Comment: @RajeshSwarnkar it's allowed if the question and answer are good and the question hasn't been answered a dozen times already. Downvoting doesn't mean it's not allowed, it means people think the answer or even the question is bad

Comment: And *this* is not a good idea to begin with. It makes an already solved problem only 100 times harder and more expensive. There are OCR programs that can handle PDFs cheaply since the 2000s. OCR was a hot AI subject back then. Needless to say, paid ones are better than the free ones provided free with scanners or the OS. OpenAI is slower, worse and more expensive than any of them. Many computer-generated PDFs don't even need OCR because they're relatively well formed text. PyPDF or tabula-py would work pretty well in these cases. OCR is needed when you have callouts, text frames etc.

Comment: In fact, I work on tens of thousands of pdfs, I've tried several free and paid tools, none of which is better than Vision API. And as far as price is concerned: Amazon Textract (the best until yesterday) gives worse results for $15/1000 images, whereas Vision API gives the best results I've had for around $0.10/1000 images (using `low` for `detail` parameter).

Comment: @Aurelien would love to know more about how the results compared across the different APIs. Which ones did you test (e.g. Google Document API)? What types of documents did you use and what info were you extracting?

Do you have a write-up somewhere?

Comment: I mainly tested [EasyOCR](https://pypi.org/project/easyocr/) and [Amazon Textract](https://aws.amazon.com/textract/) as OCR, then asked questions about the extracted text using gpt-4 VS asked questions about the document (3 first pages) using gpt-4-vision-preview. I haven't tried the Google Document API. I extracted data such as company name, publication date, company sector, etc. from company reports. For the results, Amazon Textract is actually the best OCR, but gpt-4-vision-preview is way more powerfull (and cheaper) as it does not only extract informations from text.